# Adding JQuery fade code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

I have two columns left and right, the right column is for a section called categories and when I click a category it opens (toggles) up that category and closes the previous one on the left column.

It all works fine, I was wondering if anybody knew how to add fade in fade out effect when clicking on a category (link)?

Heres my JQuery code:

```
jQuery('.tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    jQuery('.tab-content ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: What do you need to fadeIn/fadeOut? You can use `$(target).fadeIn(miliseconds)` and `$(target).fadeOut(miliseconds)`, or even in CSS with better performance and cleaner code (transition or animation through `opacity` property)

Comment: Where would you add that code in here? every time the link is clicked I want the content that hides to fade out and the content that shows to fade in

Comment: what do you need to fadein/out? It's my first question.... please, add the HTML and tell us what do you need to fadein/out,

Comment: Yes sorry about that, I found this code pen: http://codepen.io/tbl/pen/dGBqLq

Comment: I put an answer. Check it :)

Answer (score 0):

You must to put the `transition` property in the CSS rules for the other states:

```
.tab-links a {
  transition:all linear 1s;
}

.tab-links a:hover {
  transition:all linear 1s;
}

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
  transition:all linear 1s;
}
```

I write `1 second` to show the effect. See it working:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grxzQa

Next time, use stacksnippets, as far as don't require external resources nor register in different services.

```js
jQuery('.tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
  var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

  // Show/Hide Tabs
  jQuery('.tab-content ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

  // Change/remove current tab to active
  jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.tab-links a {
  padding:9px 15px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px;
  background:#7FB5DA;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:600;
  color:#4c4c4c;
  transition:all linear 1s;
}

.tab-links a:hover {
  background:#a7cce5;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition:all linear 1s;
}

li.active a, li.active a:hover {
  background:#fff;
  color:#4c4c4c;
  transition:all linear 1s;
}

/*----- Content of Tabs -----*/

.tab {
  display:none;
}

.tab.active {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-links">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Tab #3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab4">Tab #4</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
    <p>Tab #1 content goes here!</p>
    <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
    <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
    <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab3" class="tab">
    <p>Tab #3 content goes here!</p>
    <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum ri.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab4" class="tab">
    <p>Tab #4 content goes here!</p>
    <p>Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut euismod tempus hendrerit. Morbi ut adipiscing nisi. Etiam rutrum sodales gravida! Aliquam tellus orci, iaculis vel.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, but the content isn't fading in and out

Comment: Is the content? I tell you that you must explain what you try to fadein/out and you don't answer me, I'm assuming that the effect will be onclick, so I attach to the tabs. Next time, explain better and answer to the questions that users makes to you, otherwise, you only obtain bad answers like all the answers in this post.

Comment: I did, but to be more specific the content of tab 1 is for example: Tab #1 content goes here!

Donec pulvinar neque sed semper lacinia. Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper nibh; quis imperdiet velit eleifend ac. Donec blandit mauris eget aliquet lacinia! Donec pulvinar massa interdum risus ornare mollis.

Answer (score -2):

Your hide()/show() functions got the "slow" option to add the fade effect.

Try this in your code `jQuery('.tab-content ' + currentAttrValue).show("slow").siblings().hide("slow");`

Cheers